# Count how many times lists are contained in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists such as

```
words_list=[['word1', 'word2','word3'],['word1', 'word2', 'word3','word4'],['word5', 'word6'],['word5', 'word6', 'word7'],['word5', 'word6', 'word7'],['... and so on ...']]
```

and I counted how many times a list is in the dataset:

```
c = Counter(tuple(x) for x in iter(words_list))
```

output:

```
Counter({('word1', 'word2','word3'): 1,
         ('word1', 'word2', 'word3','word4'): 1,
         ('word5', 'word6'): 1,
         ('word5', 'word6', 'word7'): 2})
```

I would like to also count as the same lists that are included in others; for example, I would like to count as one

```
('word1', 'word2','word3')
('word1', 'word2', 'word3','word4')
```

and

```
('word5', 'word6')
('word5', 'word6', 'word7')
('word5', 'word6', 'word7')
```

My expected output should be

```
('word1', 'word2', 'word3','word4'): 2
('word5', 'word6', 'word7'): 3 # UPDATED!
```

(or, alternatively - this would be actually better as a user let me notice:

```
('word1', 'word2', 'word3'): 2
('word5', 'word6'): 3 # UPDATED!
```

considering the smallest groups)

To check if a list is contained in another one (separated) list, I would do

```
def removeElements(x, y): 
    for i in range(len(y)-len(x)+1): 
        for j in range(len(x)): 
            if y[i + j] != x[j]: 
                break
        else: 
            return True
    return False
```

and this would give me a boolean value, so I could count the cases where the value is True. However I think this is not a good way to proceed...

Comment: Did you mean `('word5', 'word6', 'word7'): 3`?

Comment: Also if you have `('word5', 'word6')` but then you also have both `('word5', 'word6', 'word7')` and `('word5', 'word6', 'word8')`, should `('word5', 'word6')` be counted twice (included in both counts)?

Comment: Hi @alaniwi. I am counting    if `('word5', 'word6')` is included in `('word5', 'word6', 'word7')`. Since it is included, I would count for `('word5', 'word6', 'word7')` three times (one from `('word5', 'word6')` and two from `('word5', 'word6','word7')` which incorporates word5 and word6 .

Comment: Yes. It would be. To avoid a double count, I should rather consider the smallest group (word5,word6) than the bigger. This is absolutely a good point

Comment: yes it was 3. I updated the question. Thanks for the spot. My fault

Comment: Seem that you are trying to count how many sublists of another list?

Comment: @Math So are you changing the spec to consider the smallest group? And would this mean that if one of the elements of `words_list` was an empty list, then the output should simply be `{(): len(words_list)}` because all the other lists are supersets of the empty list?

Comment: Of course, empty list should be excluded. If it would more difficult with the smallest, it would be also perfect with the biggest.But yes, as you let me notice, with the smallest would be better to avoid double counts.

Comment: The `iter` in `in iter(words_list)` is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this:

```
words_list = [['word1', 'word2','word3'],['word1', 'word2', 'word3','word4'],['word5', 'word6'],['word5', 'word6', 'word7'],['word5', 'word6', 'word7']]
words_list = sorted(words_list, reverse=True) # Sort words_list so the potential similar lists align

d = []
c = []

for i,l in enumerate(words_list):
    if i < len(words_list)-1:
        if l not in d:
            d.append(l)
            c.append(1)
        if all([w in l for w in words_list[i+1]]): # If all the strings in the list of the next index are in the current list
            c[d.index(l)]+=1 # Add to the count

for i,l in enumerate(d):
    if c[i] == 1: # If count of that index is 1
        d.pop(i)
        c.pop(i)

for i,l in enumerate(d):
    print(f"{d[i]}: {c[i]}")
```

Output:

```
['word5', 'word6', 'word7']: 3
['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']: 2
```

Comment: Hi Ann Zen. Yes, this is what I was looking for. May I ask you a question on it? If I would consider the smallest group, rather than the biggest, would be pretty the same? e.g. `['word5', 'word6']` instead of `['word5', 'word6','word7']`

Comment: You can say that.

Comment: I appended `['foo']` to the original `words_list` and it just seemed to be completely ignored.

Comment: If you want to list that, remove this part of the code: `for i,l in enumerate(d):
    if c[i] == 1: # If count of that index is 1
        d.pop(i)
        c.pop(i)`

Answer (score 0):

For convenience and using dictionary, element of list replaced by string.
If a not related element exist, it may not found ! To avoid this condition, you can remark last two statements before return in function find.

```py
from itertools import combinations

def find(words_list):
    if len(words_list) == 0:
        return {}, {}
    word_list = list(map(' '.join, map(sorted, words_list)))
    upper = {item:1 for item in word_list}
    lower = {item:1 for item in word_list}
    for word1, word2 in combinations(word_list, 2):
        if word1 == word2:
            pass
        elif word1 in word2:
            lower[word1] = lower[word1] + 1 if word1 in lower else 1
            upper[word2] = upper[word2] + 1 if word2 in upper else 1
        elif word2 in word1:
            lower[word2] = lower[word2] + 1 if word2 in lower else 1
            upper[word1] = upper[word1] + 1 if word1 in upper else 1
    upper = {key:value for key, value in upper.items() if value != 1}
    lower = {key:value for key, value in lower.items() if value != 1}
    return upper, lower

words_list=[['word1', 'word2', 'word3'],
            ['word1', 'word2', 'word3','word4'],
            ['word5', 'word6'],
            ['word5', 'word6', 'word7'],
            ['word5', 'word6', 'word7']]

upper, lower = find(words_list)
print(upper)
print(lower)
```

Comment: Hi Jason. Unfortunately your answer does not count how many sublists f another list there are.

Comment: Update as request !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.  No promises about efficiency, because it may take O(n^2) time.

```
from collections import Counter

words_list=[['word1', 'word2','word3'],['word1', 'word2', 'word3','word4'],['word5', 'word6'],['word5', 'word6', 'word7'],['word5', 'word6', 'word7']]

c = Counter(tuple(x) for x in iter(words_list))

counts = dict((tuple(k), v) for k, v in c.items())

print("BEFORE:", counts)

if () in counts:
    del(counts[()])

items = list(counts.items())

for k, _ in items:
    if k not in counts:
        # skip if one we already deleted
        continue

    setk = set(k)
    # compare with all the others
    for kother, count_other in items:
        if k == kother:
            continue
        if setk.issubset(set(kother)):
            counts[k] += count_other
            del(counts[kother])

print("\nAFTER:", counts)
```

Gives:

```
BEFORE: {('word1', 'word2', 'word3'): 1, ('word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4'): 1, ('word5', 'word6'): 1, ('word5', 'word6', 'word7'): 2}

AFTER: {('word1', 'word2', 'word3'): 2, ('word5', 'word6'): 3}
```

Comment: This implements the smallest group, as we discussed.

Comment: thank you so much alaniwi. Unfortunately I get an error because of del(counts[kother]). It is a key erroor